# Machine Code in Xcode Console

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, console

Reopened an Xcode (4.6.2) iOS6 project this morning and all of a sudden I'm getting loads of what looks like Machine code output to my Xcode console:

```
:EXACTLY...
:BRANCH(
:BRANCH...
:BOL...
:OPEN1...
:BRANCH(
:BRANCH...
:ANYOF(
:ANYOF...
:ANYOF(
:ANYOF...
:BRANCH(
:BRANCH...
:BOL...
```

**That's a tiny taster. There is a lot more. Where might it be coming from and how can I get rid of it?**

Comment: do a clean and build again.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but if you do a `rm -r ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` that might well take care of the problem.

Comment: @codeinzone Nope. Still a wall of junk.

Comment: @bdesham Unfortunately that hasn't helped.